# SQL - Get a reference to a table in a subquery

Tags: sql

Is it possible to access a table from a subquery?

```
Select d.table_c.*
from (with table_c as (select *
                       from table_a)
      select *
      from table_b
      where table_a.id = table_b.id) as d
```

table_c is inside the subquery of d, I've tried to access it using d.table_c, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: [WITH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) needs to be the first thing in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use CTE as subquery.  But you can write like below.

```
;WITH table_c
as
(SELECT * FROM table_a)
SELECT *
from table_b b
INNER JOIN table_c c on c.id = b.id
```